# Embedding Tensorflow.js in EPUB?

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, epub, tensorflow.js, epub3

I've been working on an EPUB eBook with interactive graphical examples, made possible by EPUB3's allowing the execution of 'arbitrary' JavaScript code.

I see that the Tensorflow.js team has done a lot of work making it possible to run tf.js on a host of browsers & various platforms, but I didn't see any mention of EPUB.

My question is: Before spending the time to starting trying to embed a (simple, custom) tf.js model in my EPUB, is it even possible?

Reason I ask: I'm just wondering if perhaps there are key features that tf.js requires, that the EPUB JS environment doesn't offer...?   (For example, I imagine things like camera and microphone access will not be supported by EPUB readers, but my google searching hasn't turned up any info on that so far.)

If it's not possible (or advisable), I'm ok continuing to write my own simple JS neural network codes from scratch, but...with tf.js it might save some work & definitely allow greater flexibility via access to other models & features.

**EDIT:** Anticipating questions:

1. "Why does it have to be EPUB?  Why can't you just put it all on the web -- thus, problem solved?"  I don't have to stick with EPUB, but that's how the project has been conceived up 'til now. It's a 'fun' constraint I'd like to stick with if possible. Otherwise, yea, it'll all just go on the web. EPUB3 does at least [allow you to reuse 'library' JS codes in multiple parts of the document.](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/2348/using-the-same-javascript-library-several-times-in-an-ebook) :-).
2. "Have you cross-posted this question to [Ebooks StackExchange](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/)?" Not yet. The TF.js pages led me to post on S.O. first.  I do know that [there are zero 'tensorflow' questions over there](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/search?q=tensorflow) as I write this post.

Comment: The question is not that clear to me. But If the epub reader can interpret js script, it means that there is a js interpreter somewhere. It is more likely that it can run tfjs scripts at least on cpu. Maybe you can add to your question your attempt in writing tfjs scripts

Comment: That's a good response.  I can repost if I run into specific problems, I just didn't want to spend a lot of effort only to find out that it's not supported for some reason.  Mods: if you want to delete this question, or mod it down somehow...whatever the category would be, feel free.

Comment: I think you can delete it yourself if you want. Glad to have helped with my comment